# Почему данный код на JQuery не работает?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Начал изучать `JQuery` и тут такая ситуация, что код не работает. Почему?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('header').hide().slideDown(3000);
});
```

```html
<h1 id="header">sadness</h1>
```

Answer (score 6):

Доступ к идентификатору через `#`:

```js
$('#header').hide().slideDown(3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<h1 id="header">sadness</h1>
```

Comment: Спасибо! А то купил книгу и код не заработал.

Comment: @YaroslavSventsitskiy Если ответ помог Вам - поставьте, пожалуйста, рядом с ним галочку